# Text field decimal entry format

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I want to show float digits in textfield upto two decimal points as entered in an ATM machine to withraw amount. like, 0.03. if i enter a new digit say 6, it would be like, 0.36 and so on.
Please suggest me the way to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

hey check this like a ATM Functionality...

```
    NSString *str = @"1234987";
    NSUInteger len = str.length;
    if (len>0) {
        if (len==1) {
            str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.0%@",str];
            NSLog(@"%@",str);
        }
        else if (len==2) {

            str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.%@",str];
            NSLog(@"%@",str);
        }
        else {
            NSString  *pointstr = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(len - 2,2)];
            NSString *Bstr = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,len-2)];
            str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",Bstr,pointstr];
            NSLog(@"\n\n FullString %@",str);
        }
    }
    else{
          str = @"0.0";
    }
```

**OutPut is : FullString 12349.87**

Enjoy with this code..

Comment: Thanks for your code, but i have to enter numbers in textfield and display as well. What would be the alternative for that?

Comment: ok i'll develop the code for your requirement if i got it then i'll post the code

Comment: Thanks paras for such an effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
     NSNumberFormatter* decimalFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [decimalFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [decimalFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
        [decimalFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *enteredPrice=[decimalFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:unitprice]];
```

You can use decimal formatter

Comment: Where do i use this, i mean which delegate method of UITextfield i can  use. As i have to display the entered numbers in a textfield.

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;

Comment: can you please make a code for me having the above method that can input characters in 0.00 format from rightmost position?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
float yourFloat = 2.45678;
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", yourFloat];
textField.text = text;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I have open sourced [SATextField](https://github.com/Stunner/SATextField) which has this functionality built-in. You'll want to set `fixedDecimalPoint` to YES.</del>

**EDIT:** I have created a new project that contains this functionality: [STAControls](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls) (specifically, use [`STAATMTextField`](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/blob/master/STAControls/STAControls/TextField/STAATMTextField.h) -- *it even supports `.` entry!*). The difference is that this project has been implemented as a legitimate subclass of `UITextField` whereas `SATextField` was merely a container class housing a `UITextField` instance.